# How to change the text of a button on clicking it in UNITY?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

[image]I want to change the text of a Button on clicking it in Unity. I am new to C#. Kindly help me out!

The script which i added to my Button Element

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Buttontextchange : MonoBehaviour {

Text Buy;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
     Buy = transform.FindChild("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

public void clicked()
{
Debug.Log("Button Buy Clicked!");
Buy.text = "i am a button!";

}
}
```

I have tried a lot of answers but its not working out for me! I have the button inside the canvas. Your help is very much appreciated !
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: you need to find the Button component, on click section click + and drag the script into the slot. Then you can find the method in the drop down. I guess you were missing that.

Comment: I already tried what u mentioned @Everts, but its not getting changed.

Comment: Yes @Umair,  NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Buttontextchange.clicked () (at Assets/Buttontextchange.cs:17)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the setup of your text and buttons.

The Buttontextchange component is on Buttontext object. I can see on the picture that object has no child. But you run:

```
void Start () {
    Buy = transform.FindChild("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
}
```

which is where you are probably getting the error. The Text object is under the Button object so you could just pass it in the onClick call.

```
public class Buttontextchange : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public void clicked(Text textRef)
    {
        Debug.Log("Button Buy Clicked!");
        textRef.text = "i am a button!";
    }
}
```

Then in the inspector you drag the text object into the parameter slot.

EDIT: User wants to change button color on click:

```
public class Buttontextchange : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public void clicked(Gameobject buttonObj)
    {
        Debug.Log("Button Buy Clicked!");
        Text text = buttonObj.GetComponentInChildren<Text>(true);
        if(text != null){
            textRef.text = "i am a button!";´
        }
        Image image = buttonObj.GetComponent<Image>();
        if(image != null){
            image.color = newColor; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Evert! You saved my day! You're always helping me in finding solutions :)  Thanks a Lot!

Comment: I added the color changing. Note that the parameter is no longer the Text component but the parent GameObject. In your case the highlighted Button object on the picture.

Comment: Thanks a ton Evert !

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the *public* c# keyword on the Text property. I have changed your script slightly so you can assign the Text and Button references from the Unity Editor

```
public class Buttontextchange : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Button BuyButton;
    public Text BuyText;

    void Start()
    {
        BuyButton.onClick.AddListener(OnButtonClicked);
        if (BuyText == null)
            BuyText = BuyButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
    }

    public void OnButtonClicked()
    {
        Debug.Log("Button Buy Clicked!");
        BuyText.text = "i am a button!";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I am getting the below error,   NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Buttontextchange.clicked () (at Assets/Buttontextchange.cs:17)  @Paradox Forge

Comment: That would mean you did not assign the "BuyText" variable in the inspector. I have adapted the script so you do not have to.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this after a click event 
 `Button.GetComponentInChildren(Text).text = "Button Clicked";`